# Can anyone do shirk unknowingly?

Tags: shirk

Is it possible that someone is doing shirk unknowingly, if so can you give me an example? And will he be sinful for this?

Answer (score -2):

Someone can do an act of shirk unknowingly and if a Muslim does an act of shirk unknowingly out of total ignorance and not being aware and not knowing any better and totally unaware that what he or she did was wrong or shirk and had no intention of sinning or doing anything that is wrong and transgressing, than he or she is excused and it is as if he or she did not do shirk because of the fact that he or she did not know any better.

It is recorded in the Sahih Hadith that a Muslim man who was dying requested his dead body to be burned to ashes so that he wouldn’t be punished by Allah. But he was ignorant that Allah (swt) can resurrect his body and is capable of anything and everything and that Allah (swt) will resurrect everyone on the Day of Judgement even after their body had been decayed and turned into dust. But because he was unaware and didn’t know any better, he died as a Muslim and died in the state of not having ever done shirk because he was ignorant and didn’t know any better so he was excused and died as a believing Muslim without being in the state of shirk or kufr